# Where are these file names coming from?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that processes CUBES, and if there is no cube name entered in the argument, the log file generated does not get the CUBE name since its blank (the file doesnt contain any content either) so everything is functioning fine, except i noticed that when i receive an email of the process log, these weird names followed by numbers are added to the attached file..(ATT96614, etc..)

here is the log generated:

[image: log generated with no cube name as expected]

here is the email with attached log...but with somehow appended random name and numbers

[image: log in email with random name and numbers]

here is the send email function i am using:

```
    Function Send-Email {
    Param (
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$SendTo,
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Subject,
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$Body,
        [Parameter(`
            Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$EmailFrom,
        [Parameter(`
            mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$attachment,
        [Parameter(`
            mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Username,
        [Parameter(`
            mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Password
    )

        $SMTPServer = $SmtpServer 
        $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$SendTo,$Subject,$Body)
        if ($attachment -ne $null) {
            $SMTPattachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
            $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($SMTPattachment)
        }
        $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SmtpPort) 
        $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
        $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password); 
        $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
        Remove-Variable -Name SMTPClient
        Remove-Variable -Name Username
        Remove-Variable -Name Password
}
```

here is the send-email called:

```
Send-EMail -EmailFrom $From_Email -SendTo $To_Email -Body "Processing job failed!`r`n`r`nPerhaps the CUBE or Process Server is invalid?" -Subject $Job_Failed_Email_Subject -attachment $process_output -Username $SmtpUser -Password $SmtpPassword
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When files are attached to emails the file names are written into the mime headers. At a guess, the method you're using to attach the file (supplying the file name to the relevant Attachment constructor) is dropping the name and generating its own

Try setting the name on the attachment directly yourself (after you create it, before you add it):

```
$SMTPattachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "log.txt";
```

Comment: ah i see so it has to do with mime! thanks for the explanation!